# OpenCV mouse callback

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV to write a program to show a pixel's position in a image and its RGB value as a bar when I click it(the example from a textbook). Now the problem is when I click another pixel, the information above showed but the last bar didn't disappear. May I know the method to remove the former bar when a new bar comes out?
Here is the code:

```
const char *source_img="source image";
IplImage *source_copy;
IplImage *imgSource; 
int pt_num=0;

void my_mouse_callback(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param){
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP){
        CvFont    font;
        uchar*    ptr;
        char      label[30];
        imgSource = (IplImage*) param;
        cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX, .40, .40, 0, 1, 8);

        ptr = cvPtr2D(imgSource, y, x, NULL);

        sprintf(label, "(%d, %d, %d, %d, %d)",x,y, ptr[0], ptr[1], ptr[2]);
        cvRectangle(
                    imgSource,
                    cvPoint(x, y-10),
                    cvPoint(x + 200, y + 8),
                    CV_RGB(0xff,0xff,0xff),
                    CV_FILLED, 
                    8, 0
                    );
        cvPutText(imgSource, label, cvPoint(x, y), &font, CV_RGB(0,0,0xff));

        cvShowImage(source_img, imgSource);

    }
}
```

Any help, please?

Comment: Your `imgSource` is passed via a pointer, so you're modifying the input image from within `my_mouse_callback`, that's why your previous bars won't dissapear.

Create a working copy of your original image within your function and use this copy to draw on.

Comment: Don't use obsolete C syntax!

Comment: @s1h OK I'll try that